# wso2 Key Store Issue

Tags: wso2

I am using `wso2 sso version 5.3`. I am configuring new `jks` key in place of `wso2carbon.jks` and followed the steps.

1. Generated key using self -signed certificate and copied key to folder `${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/test2.jks`
   **Command** : `- keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias wso2carbon -keystore keystore.jks -validity 360`
2. updated the new `carbon.xml` with new `test2.jks` file.

   ```
   <KeyStore>
       <!-- Keystore file location-->
       <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/test2.jks</Location>
       <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
       <Type>JKS</Type>
       <!-- Keystore password-->
       <Password>xxxxxx</Password>
       <!-- Private Key alias-->
       <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
       <!-- Private Key password-->
       <KeyPassword>xxxxxx</KeyPassword>
   </KeyStore>
   ```

**Error message:**

> Exception While Calling from Java using the Axis 2 library. "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

**Code Snippet:**

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

    final String SERVER_URL = "https://XXXXXXX:9443/services/"; 
    //setting jks key
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "test2.jks"); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "XXXXX"); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");

    try{     
        String cookie = null;
        AuthenticationAdminStub authstub = new AuthenticationAdminStub(SERVER_URL+"AuthenticationAdmin");

        // Authenticates as a user having rights to add users. 
        if (authstub.login(XXXXXX, XXXXXX, null)) { 
            cookie = (String) authstub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().getProperty( 
                    HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING); 
            System.out.println("cookie "+cookie);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting absolute path for `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`.